# Что(,) орлицы обгонят по баллам другие команды?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, выбор-слов, кавычки

Нужна запятая?

А слово "баллы" в данном контексте при чём? Баллы в состязании?
*Что(,) орлицы обгонят по баллам другие команды?*

Comment: Вопрос очень простой, тема известная. Попробуйте дать ответ сами.  "Орлицы" пишутся в кавычках, условность надо обозначить.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131

Comment: Кстати, я могла бы этот вопрОс закрыть, так как у автора была единственная метка: ЗАПЯТЫЕ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А мне вопрос понравился.
Да, поначалу показалось, что он "очень простой, тема известная". Но я увидела здесь некоторые "интересности", в том числе и логические.

• Первая. **Об орлицах**

Если имеется в виду команда с таким названием, то пишется так: "**О**рлицы" (в кавычках и прописной буквы).
Если же имеются в виду игроки (девушки или женщины) команды "Орёл" (или "Орлы") или просто из города Орла (орловчанки), то их возможное прозвище пишется так: "**о**рлицы" (в кавычках и со строчной буквы).

• Вторая. **О запятой**

Её нет в таком диалоге:
*— Ты в этом уверен?

— В чём? **Что** "орлицы" обгонят?.. Уверен!*

А в этом есть:
*— Сомневаюсь я в твоём прогнозе.

— **Что,** "Орлицы" обгонят по баллам?..

— Да, я уже прикинул.*

• Третья. Собственно **об обогнать** и **о баллах**

[Обогнать](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (ТС Кузнецова) — **2.** Достичь больших по сравнению с кем-либо успехов, результатов; превзойти кого-либо, оказаться впереди в каком-либо отношении.

Есть виды спорта, в которых победа действительно определяется *по баллам*, а не по секундам (кто быстрее), не по метрам (кто дальше, или выше, или глубже), не по килограммам (кто больше поднимет).
Это художественная гимнастика, фигурное катание, многоборье, прыжки в воду...

> ...Ирина Винер-Усманова жестко прокомментировала судейство и сравнила сегодняшний скандал с не менее не справедливым решением судей по отношению к Авериной на Олимпийских играх в Токио, когда Линой Ашрам, уронив снаряд, **обогнала по баллам** российскую спортсменку, идеально выполнившую свою программу.